# Jquery - each() eq() click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, each, var

I want to take two items of data received from HTML5 and use them in the click function and in the functions inside it.

I'm having a problem so here's my code so far:

```
var test = [];

// This is a div class .quiz_list_row the ids are counted as #1 #2 #3...
$(".quiz_list_row").each(function(index){
    // Gets the data necessary
    //  It comes from data-quizlist-id (HTML5)
    $quiz_list_id = $(this).eq(index).data("quizlistId");

    //  It comes from data-quizlevel-reached (HTML5)
    $quiz_level_reached = $(this).eq(index).data("quizlevelReached");

    test[index] = $quiz_list_id;

    // testing
    alert("quiz_list_id: " +$quiz_list_id);
    alert("level: "+$quiz_level_reached);

    // click functions
    $(this).click(function(){

        // bla bla
        // alert(test[index]) ???
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you try it? What problem are you having?

Comment: @SLaks I tried and I get the first result but not the second row and so on..

Comment: I succeeded in getting the results. but they're inverted and it's weird because the "data" filed from html have the ordered data! I'll send another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing `.eq()`. Try this (I've removed the calls to `.eq()`):

```
var test = [];

    // This is a div class .quiz_list_row the ids (inside it) are counted as #1 #2 #3...
$(".quiz_list_row").each(function(index){

    // Gets the data necessary
               //  It comes from data-quizlist-id (HTML5)
    $quiz_list_id = $(this).data("quizlistId");
               //  It comes from data-quizlevel-reached (HTML5)
    $quiz_level_reached = $(this).data("quizlevelReached");

    test[index] = $quiz_list_id;

    // testing
    alert("quiz_list_id: " +$quiz_list_id);
    alert("level: "+$quiz_level_reached);

    // click functions
    $(this).click(function(){

          // bla bla
          // alert(test[index]) ???
    });
});
```

You may just want this:

```
$(".quiz_list_row").click(function(){
    var $quiz_list_id = $(this).data("quizlistId");
    var $quiz_level_reached = $(this).data("quizlevelReached");

    alert("quiz_list_id: " +$quiz_list_id);
    alert("level: "+$quiz_level_reached);
});
```

Comment: `$quiz_list_id` and `$quiz_level_reached` aren't defined on the first code block.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann That was the modified OP code (simply removing the `.eq(index)`). The second block is the revised/refactored solution.

Comment: I really need the each because I want to get the data from every row. Thank you for the tip about eq()! I still have a problem to get the results for every row =/

Answer (score 0):

Use a closure around the click event

```
    // testing
    alert("quiz_list_id: " + $quiz_list_id);
    alert("level: " + $quiz_level_reached);

    // click functions
    (function(num) {
        $(this).click(function() {

            alert(test[num]) ? ? ?
        });
    })(index);

});​
```